# Color cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm getting a weird error, I am unable to set the color of a paint object with a Color object, this is strange seeing as how `paint.setColor(Color.RED)` is valid whilst `paint.setColor(this.color)` is not

Here is the code that I have.

```
public class Shape{
    protected GameView2 game_view;
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected Color color;

    public Shape(GameView2 game_view, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.game_view = game_view;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rec = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        paint.setColor(this.color); //does not work
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(rec, paint);        
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

the Shape object has been declared another class called GameView,
its very big so I wont paste the whole class, but when creating a Shape object this is what is done:

```
new Shape(this, Color.BLACK, 0, 0, 100, 100)
```

The error I get is `incompatible types: Color cannot be converted to int`

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Can you please add the code of the class Paint?

Comment: read the doc. specifically the doc for `Color.BLACK` or `Color.RED`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`setColor`** requires **int** type but **`this.color`** is not **`int`**, you try to set the color object instead of int value.

```
public native void setColor(int color);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I've changed `Color color` to `int color`

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html), you see that `Color` is a utility class that privides static methods to deal with color ints. That you actually can instantiate a `Color` object seems to be a historical mistake.

Comment: yep. I don't get why Color is not abstract. It does not make much sense to instanciate one.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing a `Color` to your new `Shape` ?

You should use

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.idcolor);
```

And in the xml :

```
<color name="idcolor">#123456</color>
```

**edit**

According to your edit, try to declare color as an `int`. A color is actually an `int`, main colors are declared as static fields in `Color`

```
protected int color;
```